# When bulk renaming a tag, also update users' interested tags

Tags: feature-request

For example, [crystalreports] has recently been renamed [crystal-reports] and whilst this might be a better name, I was a little confused as to :

1. Why I could find anything tagged as [crystalreports] (can it not issue a redriect to search for the replacement tag?)
2. Why it still showed as an interested tag, given it had been "retired"

Comment: I suggest that the "retired" tag just be updated to the "proper" tag. I really don't care, as long as it works!

Comment: I definitely agree.  In the past two months or so, winforms became windows-forms and is now winforms again.  Both of these changes occurred without updating my favorite tags, which led to moments of confusion as I searched for what "proper" tag was in vogue.

Comment: This happened to me recently on SuperUser with "open-office" being changed to "open-office.org". I think it could be considered a bug rather than a feature request, would be good to see it fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree!

I just found out from the [How can we stop people from tagging questions “WinForms”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9109/how-can-we-stop-people-from-tagging-questions-winforms) question that "WinForms" is no longer a "liked" tag on StackOverflow, and that "Windows-Forms" is now preferred.

"WinForms" was one of my "Interesting" tags. (I've since removed it and replaced it with windows-forms).

My question, though, is: is there any way that could have been automatically updated to the preferred tag? Leaving that tag there didn't make me realize we shouldn't use it anymore, and I might have posted another question using it.

Is there some way both the Interesting and Ignored tags sections on the sites could be updated as the tags are reorged and combined?

Answer (score 0):

I agree. The one that affected me: someone changed `python-3.x` to `python-3`. Then a few weeks later, changed it all back again.

The next time a user clicks on the tag in their list, they get an empty list, with no explanation. Everyone has to go hunting, figure out what changed, and update their list.

The advantage is obvious--reduced hassle by users.

I can't think of many disadvantages:

- The effort to implement it.
- What if it's only a partial rename, or a tag gets split into several new tags?