# Highlight the tag that marks a question as interesting

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

I'm interested in seeing which tag is responsible for marking a question as 'interesting'. A slight change to its visual representation would be enough.

Comment: Someone else thinks there's too much time spent on tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11372/ (not a dupe) let alone highlighting the glow worm.

Comment: How many interesting tags have you set?

Comment: On SO, around 50.

Comment: ...why? We have bloody wildcards. `*sql*` gets you everything with `sql` in the tag.

Comment: I'm already using wildcards.

Comment: But you do have questions on the front page which are *not* highlighted as interesting, don't you?

Comment: @mafutrct: You have 50 interesting tags, including wildcards? But, you've almost exclusively answered C# tags...so something's telling me there's a very, very low signal to noise ratio in that list.

Comment: @Eric: that does not mean anything. Being interested in does not mean you can answer the stuff. Maybe he just wants to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions only have 5 tags max. If you put a tag on your interested list, the very fact that the row in question is highlighted should be indication enough to remind you which of the tags in the question is calling for your attention.

Unless, as implied in comment, you have so many that you don't know what's in your list anymore.

Comment: Looks like it is a memory overflow on the human being side.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be more distracting than helpful. When everything on the page has a special color, then the colors aren't really special anymore.

Cheapo freehand visual aid:
[image: graph of inverted parabola with ease of use as y-axis and visual cues as x-axis]

Answer (score 1):

Alconja wrote a [greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) for this