# Highlight interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

With the recent addition of the Adobe logo to the Adobe based tags, I came to realize that my eye was scanning these tags first when browsing the question list.

As I was thinking more about how much this may affect my Stack Overflow experience - I thought that perhaps a little JavaScript adding a "star" to your interesting tags / something else for ignored tags **might** be very useful.  You could quickly spot a question that is in 3 of your tags (as opposed to just 'any of my tags') while scanning the questions list.  It would also quickly draw your eye to WHY the question is interesting to you.

Honestly - This could even be accomplished by altering the border properties of interesting tags (like feature-request/etc end up looking here)

A greasemonkey userscript if you want to see what it might look like: [grab from here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59123)

[mock http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/2992/picture1oj.png](http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/2992/picture1oj.png)

Another quick screenshot using highlighting instead of an icon:
[mock2 http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/5945/picture2ps.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/5945/picture2ps.png)

Comment: But which one of those tags is on your list of interest?

Comment: jquery/javascript/php are all 'interesting' tags in the screenshot - my example hard codes the stack overflow icon - but a star or something else could easily be used.

Comment: This is kind of complete. Hovering on a favourite tag will show a yellow star in your bubble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight the tag that marks a question as interesting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/highlight-the-tag-that-marks-a-question-as-interesting)

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea quite a bit. Of your two suggested methods, I would prefer the second, unless the graphic used were star or something similar - the SO logo would not effectively communicate this meaning to me.

Note that with the borders, you could have green borders to indicate tags from your interested list and red borders to indicate tags from your ignore list.

Comment: Definitely agree with the red v green border as this makes it instantly obvious and is very user friendly (though it may turn out to be visually unappealing...)

Answer (score -2):

For me, there is no difference if there is 1 or 3 tags that make a question interesting.

Comment: It would also quickly draw your eye to WHY the question is interesting to you.  I have quite a few tags on my interesting list.

Comment: And for me i have very few interesting tags. There are both kinds.