# Favourite tags must be highlighted

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I have just marked few tags as my favourite. As given below it highlights all the questions related to my Favourite tag. However, it does not highlight which is my favourite tag in that particular question.

My suggestion is to highlight the user's favourite tag for those particular questions. Isn't it good to have some color surronding the favourite tag, so I know which is my favourite tag for such questions?

[image: Favourites tag]

Comment: Why do you need it? You *know* what's your favorite tags, don't you? :)

Comment: @Shadow - Yes, indeed you are right. But once I have lots of them as favourite, it might not strike me at first glance and takes me couple of seconds to realize my fav tag. Tough I know, this is not such a critical feature request, I was just wondering that it would be good, thats all... :)

Comment: @Sac good point but I believe they have "higher priority" requests planned so if I were you I wouldn't expect this to be implemented any time soon. :)

Comment: @Shadow - Yes, infact I am only suggesting this as request. I have only posted it here, so that it can be in repository of meta for sometime in future...tough with low priority anyway... :)

Comment: An innocent mistake... after all, we changed the terminology from "interesting" to "favorite". But this remains a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24539/highlight-interesting-tags) [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/highlight-the-tag-that-marks-a-question-as-interesting). I'm closing as the former which has more options and more depth than the older question.

Comment: Argh, @Grace Note does it again. I'll move my answer over to the dupe.

Comment: @Popular If it makes you feel any better, you prompted the search yourself by bumping the question to my attention with an answer.

Comment: @Grace I wasn't feeling bad in the first place, but... _yay, I'm helping!_

Comment: @Grace, @Popular - Thanks guys. No issues. I have myself voted for closing this question too.. :)